# Wildcard / regular expression not working in snakemake?

Tags: regex, wildcard, snakemake

I'm a beginner with snakemake. I'm trying to understand how to use variables and regular expressions. I've tried to follow tutorials and...I still need help. I the following example, what I'd like my code to do is "run this, for files in directory 'data' that are named gene_dna and have any extension".
I would like to understand why this code doesn't work:

```
rule test:
    input:
        "data/gene_dna.{.+}"
    output:
        "test.txt"
    shell:
        "echo 1 > {output}"
```

...but this one does (at least during a dry-run). The difference is ".txt." instead if {.+}:

```
rule test:
    input:
        "data/gene_dna.txt"
    output:
        "test.txt"
    shell:
        "echo 1 > {output}"
```

Please help?

Comment: `"data/gene_dna\.[^.]+$"`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm afraid it does not work. Same issue as before, it gives me 'Missing input files for rule test:'

Comment: Using regexes in wildcards is used to restrict their allowed values, not to find files to match :) https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#wildcards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file_pattern = "data/gene_dna.{ext}"
extensions = glob_wildcards(file_pattern).ext

rule all:
    input:
        expand("test.{ext}", ext=extensions)


rule test:
    input:
        "data/gene_dna.{ext}"
    output:
        "test.{ext}"
    shell:
        "echo 1 > {output}"
```

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering, is there a way to 'lose' variables on the way? For instance, I don't need the {ext} in the output, actually I'd prefer to not to drag it around for the rest of my workflow. But it looks as if I need to mention it in the output...

Comment: But you might have multiple files called `data/gene_dna.{ext}`, then `data/gene_dna.txt` and `data/gene_dna.csv` would both be turned into `data/gene_dna` overwriting the first result. Snakemake does not allow this. Ps. If my answer solved your q please accept and create a new q. You are allowed to ask as many as you would like :)